# Django - doing an internal view post

Tags: django, rest, post

I have a Django app that has two view requests. The first request ("add_item") is the add request, which does some validation and then ultimately adds an item to a user's queue. The second request hits a user's facebook feed, iterates through the posts, and adds some of them to their queue. Ideally, I don't want to replicate the logic for the add in that second request. I'd rather just call the first request within the second request's loop.

I can't figure out how to do this and still pass in the user's context in the request. Does anyone have an example of how to do this? I tried passing in the POST data and the user context that the first request requires:

```
request = { "POST": { "queue_id": 1, "data": "some_data_to_add" }, "user": request.user }
add_item(request)
```

However, request.user doesn't get serialized properly. I'm also pretty sure I can't just pass the POST data that way, I'm sure it also needs to be serialized somehow. In general, I think this is not the standard way to do something like this.

Comment: Refactor out the code that actually does the work into a separate function, and call that code from both views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate a view which perform the task of adding items into the queue and call that function from both first and second view.

for example:

```
def adding_items(<necessary params>):
    item add logic here.

def first_view(request):
    # call adding items to update queue.
    adding_items( <params> )

def second_view(request):
    # call adding items to update queue.
    adding_items( <params> )
```

Thats it :)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. Ignacio, sounds like you concur :)